# I found these parts but have no idea what sets - lots of grey and black, looks like Star Wars

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Can anyone identify what sets these parts belong to?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

That dish in the baggie was only ever in one set: [7748 Corporate Alliance Tank Droid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7748-1)

[image: 7748]

The decorated windscreen below seems to be Windscreen 6 x 6 x 3 Canopy Half Sphere with Dual 2 Fingers with SW Sith Fighter Pattern which was only in one set: [9500 Sith Fury-class Interceptor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9500-1)

[image: 9500]

I wonder if that base on the lower left is [10186 General Grievous - UCS](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10186-1)

[image: 10186]

The one at the top is cut off. But based on

- Dark Bluish Gray Tile, Modified 4 x 4 with Studs on Edge
- Dark Bluish Gray Wedge, Plate 4 x 2 Left
- Light Bluish Gray Technic, Liftarm, Modified Bent Thin L-Shape 3 x 3

The only set with all 3 seems to be [75104-1 75104-1 Kylo Ren's Command Shuttle](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75104-1)

[image: 75104]

The one on the lower right with the orange seems to be a freezing chamber, but I might not know which one:

Based on

- Dark Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove and Bottom Stud Holder (Jumper)
- Dark Bluish Gray Wedge, Plate 4 x 4
- Trans-Clear Plate 1 x 2

it would either be [75222-1 Betrayal at Cloud City](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75222-1) or, more likely, [75137-1 Carbon-Freezing Chamber](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75137-1) as Cloud City doesn't have any 32474 Black Technic Ball Joint which I think I see in the photo.

[image: 75137]

Comment: Nice finds! The blue tower on the left is from [6873](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6873-1), the black curved slope construct looks much like the top of [75227](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75227-1), and the small build with door on the right looks like the 'fridge' in [41119](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41119-1).